# audio_service crashed with error at audio_service_engine

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-service

I uploaded a Flutter app on PlayStore and some cases was reported and the log is like below:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3654)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3806)
  at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute (LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks (TransactionExecutor.java:135)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:95)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2267)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: The requested cached FlutterEngine did not exist in the FlutterEngineCache: 'audio_service_engine'
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.setupFlutterEngine (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onAttach (FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragment.onAttach (FlutterFragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach (Fragment.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate (FragmentManager.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate (FragmentController.java)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate (FragmentActivity.java)
  at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity.onCreate (FlutterFragmentActivity.java)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7963)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7952)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1307)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3629)
```

I tried to google but it didn't give good result so I don't even know what is firstly wrong. what would be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

See [this bug report](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/964) . If you're already using the latest version and it's not fixed, you will need to submit a new bug report to get it fixed. If you're *not* already using the latest version, then doing so will probably fix it.